# Use of undeclared identifier, only when profiling app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I'm getting an error, but only when profiling my app using the simulator:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'DEBUG'
```

Any ideas as to how to fix this? The only time this occurs is specifically when profiling my app with the simulator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably running the profile in `RELEASE` mode. `DEBUG` can be defined at compile time with some build settings. Check within Xcode your current scheme settings. In your profile scheme, if your `Build Configuration` is set to anything other than DEBUG, this is likely the culprit. If you'd like to check for the existence of DEBUG try something like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
      // do some things
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks! Stupid mistake on my part, was checking for the existence of DEBUG incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

It also happened to me when I Run App in Release.
I resolve it by this step:
1. Select your target;
2. Select Build Settings;
3. Search "Preprocessor Macros";
4. Check if [DEBUG=0] is in Release line or not;
5. If not, add [DEBUG=0] and then Run again.

Comment: This solved it perfectly for me!

We were using 2 ways of checking if it was debug vs release mode:

`#ifdef DEBUG`
and
`return DEBUG ? CLIENT_ID_DEBUG : CLIENT_ID_RELEASE;`

Rather than change the code everywhere, making sure DEBUG=0 was set for release did the trick.